# ZF 2 and Doctrine 2, print relation result

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I created a list of users and each user has a statusID. This statusID is a FK to the table status.

I´m able to persist but when I need to print this list I´m not able to show the status name, only the statusID from the user table. My code below:

```
$repository = $this->getEm()->getRepository($this->entity);
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder("u");
$adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($query));
$paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(10);
```

At my view, I loop the results.

```
forech ($this->user as $user) $user->getStatus()->getName();
```

It returns:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object
```

With I var_dump($paginator) it will not bring the oneToMany relation I created.

Entity\User

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Sistema\Entity\Status", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "merge", "refresh", "remove"})
* @var Collection
*/
protected $status;
```

Entity\Status

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SimplaUser\Entity\User", inversedBy="status", cascade={"persist", "merge", "refresh", "remove"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="statusID", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false, nullable=false)
* @ORM\Column(name="statusID", type="integer")
* @var User|null
*/
protected $user;
```

How is possible to get the User and the Status and print it at the view?

Best regard´s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was at the relation Column property.

```
* @ORM\Column(name="statusID", type="integer")
```

I removed it and it solved, now my entity is like:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SimplaUser\Entity\User", inversedBy="status", cascade={"persist", "merge", "refresh", "remove"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="statusID", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false, nullable=false)
* @var User|null
*/
protected $user;
```

Sorry for posting and replying at the same moment, but it was a try out that works. Hope this can help anyone on the future.

Best regard´s.